# Unable to Sign in Through Facebook in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-facebook-login

I want to use Facebook Sign-in in my Flutter app. For this, I'm using the Flutter package flutter_facebook_auth 4.3.0. And configure my android app on my Facebook developer account.
When the application started or I tried to make a Sign in request:
I'm getting this message:

E/com.facebook.GraphResponse( 3869): {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating application. Invalid application ID.}

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and now I finally found a solution, so here is what worked for me.

**TL;DR**

1. Make sure to have this in your Android Manifest file:

   ```xml
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
   ```

   Along with the *strings.xml* file with the app id mentioned in the Facebook Login documentation.
2. Comment out this line in your app level *build.gradle* file:

   ```
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0' // comment this out!
   ```

**Explanation**: A problem that occured *before* the problem you mention, was that having the reference to the application ID from *strings.xml* in your Android Manifest as described in the Facebook login documentation like this:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

caused this build error:

> ```
> Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value value=(@string/facebook_app_id) from (unknown)
> is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-60 value=(@string/facebook_application_id).
> ```

And the "solution" mentioned on an old Github post (reference missing) stated that you should just comment the reference out in your Android Manifest - and sure enough this removed the build error, but then another problem came.

**The new issue that came along**
was basically that during the bulid, a Facebook application ID of "CHANGE-ME" was written for the string value that should have been read from your *strings.xml* - you can see this in VScode if you just search for "CHANGE-ME", then you'll find a *value.xml* file containing this wrong ID, and even if you change it in this file it doesn't solve the problem.

**What solved the issue for me**
was commenting out the implementation causing the clash resulting in the build error instead, which is in your app level *build.gradle*:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0' // comment this out!
```

And *leave in* the reference to your *strings.xml* app ID in your Android Manifest file, so the application ID is written correctly.

I have tested all the firebase functionality I use in my app to see if any issues came from commenting this out, but I haven't found any issues yet. I use and have tested these features after commenting out:

- Realtime database
- Email/password sign in
- Google Sign in
- Facebook Sign in

Hope this helps.